# iOS 13 background location updates permission clarification

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, ios13

I'm struggling to get my app to get background location updates with the 'when in use' permission setting on iOS 13. It works perfectly fine with the always permission, but i want 'When in use'.

I have been told that all I need is the background mode enabled in the info plist. I have these enabled, below is the snippet from my info plist.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Used for location services</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Permission</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Permission</string>

<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

So in short, in iOS 13 is it possible to get background location updates with either the provisional always permission or when in use permission?

EDIT:

below is the function that starts tracking the users location:

```
 public static async Task StartJourneyTracking()
    {
        try
        {
            InitialiseJourney();
            if (Geolocator.IsListening) return;
            CLLocationManager manager = new CLLocationManager();
            manager.ShowsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true;
            Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy =                   
                  TrackingConstants.GeoLocatorDesiredAccuracy;
            await Geolocator.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(
                TrackingConstants.GeoLocatorMinimumTime),
                TrackingConstants.GeoLocatorMinimumDistance, false, new 
                ListenerSettings()
                {
                    ActivityType = ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                    AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                    DeferLocationUpdates = false,
                    PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
                });
            IsLocationServiceRunning = true;

            Geolocator.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
            Geolocator.PositionError += PositionError;
            ShowNotification();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            InstanceManager.LoggingHelper().TrackError(e);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 18/11/2019

With the advice taken from the comments I have seen some changes in behaviour.

With provisional always permission journey logging does NOT get location updates when the app is minimised in the background. If i leave journey logging running in the background (not getting location updates) and wait for the second prompt to come up asking to keep when in use or change to always. Selecting when in use makes the background location indicator bar appear instantly and journey logging seems to be able to get location updates in the background.

However, if I now tap on the background indicator bar bringing the app to the foreground and end journey logging (stop location updates) and restart it (start location updates) without changing the permissions, I no longer see the blue background indicator bar and journey logging stops receiving location updates in the background.

Any ideas?

Thanks again

Comment: You need to set [`allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates) to `true`

Comment: its set to true in jamesmontemagno geolocator plugin? Or do i need to set it to true in the cl location manager aswell?

Comment: i'll set it on my CLlocationmanager and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Looking more closely, the `CLLocationManager` instance you are allocating here isn't actually doing anything since it is just a local variable and will be discarded as soon as this method returns. Presumably the location manager that is actually being used is inside `GeoLocator`

Comment: @Jhardy, I apologize for the answer I gave. It was not accurate. I have removed it Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639469/difference-between-always-and-while-using-app-in-location-services-for-ios

Comment: I completely oversaw that mistake. I'll move in to a static class variable so it isn't disregarded. And yes the Geolocator sits on top of the CLLocationManager for iOS.

Comment: You can post  the answer and accept it , it is a common issue and will help more people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Turns out that the geolocator plugin does not seem to configure correctly with iOS 13 permissions. I switched out the geolocator for iOS's CLLocationManager and it worked first time.